# ASP MVC ajax() call problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, parameters

My view:

```
var token = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Account/TryRegister',
    type: 'post',
    data: { '__RequestVerificationToken': token,
            firstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
            lastName: $('#LastName').val(),
            email: $('#Email').val(),
            password: $('#Password').val() },
    success: function (outData) {
        alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error!');
    }
});
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult TryRegister(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password)
{
    return Json(true); // TEMP!
}
```

If I remove firstName, lastName, email and password from both, it works, otherwise, it just doesn't get to the controller. What am I missing here (all fields really exist)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make life easier on yourself and use JQuery's .serialize()

```
var formdata;

formdata= $(myform).serialize();
```

then in your ajax call...
data: formdata,

Comment: There was another problem somewhere else. My bad. Thank you anyway ;)